# How to make a surrounding Ruby block "conditional"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a Ruby block like the following:

```
<%= a_method("with_argument") do %>
  My code...
<% end %>
```

I would like to make the surrounding method `a_method("with_argument")` "conditional" the Ruby (on Rails) way. That is, `a_method("with_argument")` should be a block for my inner code only if a condition is true.

At this time, to achieve that, in Ruby on Rails I'm using code like this:

```
<% my_inner_code = capture do %>
  My code...
<% end %>

<% if my_condition %>
  <%= a_method("with_argument") do %>
    <%= my_inner_code %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= my_inner_code %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any Ruby (on Rails) way to make the surrounding block "conditional"?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you give a real example using an actual method?

Comment: @Beartech It is completely clear. See the "At this time" code: OP wants `my_inner_code` to be wrapped by `a_method("with_argument")` if `my_condition`, otherwise leave `my_inner_code` as-is, without having the code be WET with repeating `my_inner_code`.

Comment: Also do you want this condition to always be a part of this method? Or just put a method inside a conditional statement? Do you want the conditional to be internal to the method?

Comment: @Beartech I think it could always be part of the method since I think I will use it a lot in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a helper method like this:

```
def wrap_with_a_method_if(condition, *args, &)
  content = capture { yield }

  if condition
    a_method(*args) { content }
  else
    content
  end
end
```

and use it like this in your views:

```
<%= wrap_with_a_method_if(condition, "with_argument") do %>
  My code ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. Should it be `&block` (instead of `&`)?

Comment: Both works. You can even remove the `&` completely because the block is not called by its name in the method, but `yield`is sued instead. I just left the unnamed `&` in the signature to make it easier to read and understand that the method will yield a block. Others suggest removing the `&block` completely because that would be a bit faster. See: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.67.2/RuboCop/Cop/Performance/RedundantBlockCall

Comment: By using `wrap_with_a_method_if(false, ...)` i.e. when the `condition` is `false` then the inner code is rendered twice instead of once. When the `condition` is `true` then it works as expected. Can it be due to the fact the `a_method(*args)` is a block method itself?

Comment: That depends a bit on what the `a_method` looks like internally. Is it possible that `a_method` uses `capture` internally?

Comment: The method is [turbo_frame_tag](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/728b963eb67e1d10a2f16c571f98799076985e2b/app/helpers/turbo/frames_helper.rb#L38).

Comment: @Backo I updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When the wrapper isn't a simple method call:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  class Unwrap
    attr_reader :content

    def initialize view
      @view = view
    end

    def wrap
      @content = @view.capture { yield }
    end
  end

  def wrap condition
    unwrap = Unwrap.new self
    wrapped = capture do
      yield unwrap
    end
    condition ? wrapped : unwrap.content
  end
end
```

```rb
<%= wrap false do |un| %>
  <%= tag.div class: "text-blue-500" do %>
    <% text = "not wrapped" %>
    <%= un.wrap do %>
      <%= text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

#=> not wrapped
```

```rb
<%= wrap true do |un| %>
  <%= tag.div class: "text-blue-500" do %>
    <% text = "wrapped" %>
    <%= un.wrap do %>
      <%= text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

#=> <div class="text-blue-500">wrapped</div>
```

---

For a bit of a universal method, to take @spickermann's answer a little further:

```rb
def wrap_if(condition, ...)
  if condition
    send(...)
  else
    yield
    nil # to avoid double concat
  end
end

def turbo_frame_tag_if(condition, ...)
  wrap_if(condition, :turbo_frame_tag, ...)
end
```

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag_if false, :frame, class: "text-blue-500" do %>
  nowrap
<% end %>
#=> nowrap

<%= turbo_frame_tag_if true, :frame, class: "text-blue-500" do %>
  wrap
<% end %>
#=> <turbo-frame class="text-blue-500" id="frame">wrap</turbo-frame>
```